# How to extend my visa in Spain to stay studying language?

Tags: spain

I had a Schengen visa to visit Spain for 90 days and took a 3-month language class. Now I want to extend my visa in Spain to study more. Any suggestions on how to do this?

I have searched some ways to apply for staying more:

- Make a couple claim certificate (I have a Spanish boyfriend in Madrid, same city I study). But I found out it said you have to live together continuously 12 months to be able to claim for that.
- Get a job. My friend's cousin owns a company here, but don't know how to make document for me to stay without going back to my country first.
- Ask the school to extend my student visa, but a visa under 6 months can’t be a student visa, and can’t be extended.

Can anyone with experience help, please?

It's a lot to go back and come back again. I even think I may stay illegally. But I don’t know what happens after that, as I will be forbidden to come back Europe.

Comment: To confirm: you had an actual visa stamped/glued in your passport? You did not enter using the 90/180 day visa free rule?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas would that make a difference?

Comment: @Phoog - Yep. If they're in the country using the visa waiver, they've probably used up the 90-day allotment, which would mean that they need to exit the Schengen zone first; but if they have an actual visa, then there mgiht be some sort of change-of-status they could avail themselves of.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas the 90-day limit applies equally to Schengen short-stay (type C) visas and visa-free entry.  Also, in countries I'm familiar with, which do not include Spain, an application for residence permission usually allows the applicant to remain while the application is decided. Whether such an application may be filed while in the country is another matter that (in the countries I'm familiar with) does not depend on whether the applicant has a C visa versus Annex II visa-free entry.